# I am getting error as "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'JsonRpcProvider') at Object"

Tags: ethers.js

##### Code

```
const ethers = require('ethers');
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    `https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/6f3012a55a604a929154e5563874fca6`);

const querryBlockchain = async() => {
    const block = await provider.getBlockNumber();
}
querryBlockchain();
```

##### ERROR

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
                                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'JsonRpcProvider')
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\boppe\OneDrive\Desktop\ethers.js\read.js:2:39)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1255:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1309:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

Comment: Which version of ethers are you using? Recently there was a v6 launched, perhaps you are using the wrong version or the wrong syntax.

Answer (score 0):

remove "providers"
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider...